# RTSP gives 401 (unauthorised) error

Tags: ios, iphone, rtsp

I am trying to fetch cctv video in my `iPhone` App. But I am getting `401 (unauthorised) error`. I read that this error is related to username and the password. But when I inquired with the concerned person he said that the camera do not have any password. Only username has been set. **I have the following link with me to run the video:**

> rtsp://admin@ip:port/videoMain

**Please note**: When I tried running the same in `VLC player` it ran successfully but same when I am accessing through code I am getting `401 error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to pass blank password?:

```
rtsp://admin:@ip:port/videoMain
```